# Best seed for parallel process

Tags: python, random, parallel-processing, seed, montecarlo

I need to run a MonteCarlo simulations in parallel on different machines. The code is in c++, but the program is set up and launched with a python script that set a lot of things, in particular the random seed. The function setseed thake a 4 bytes unsigned integer

Using a simple

```
import time
setseed(int(time.time()))
```

is not very good because I submit the jobs to a queue on a cluster, they remain pending for some minutes then they starts, but the start time is impredicible, it can be that two jobs start at the same time (seconds), so I switch to:

```
setseet(int(time.time()*100))
```

but I'm not happy. What is the best solution? Maybe I can combine information from: time, machine id, process id. Or maybe the best solution is to read from /dev/random (linux machines)?

How to read 4 bytes from /dev/random?

```
f = open("/dev/random","rb")
f.read(4)
```

give me a string, I want an integer!

Comment: You havent actually said what consitutes "best". I take it that you are trying to insure that each instance uses a different seed. But, should they be unique between different jobs in a single run, or do you need something approaching (or guaranteed to be) global uniqueness (all run and all jobs). Secondly, do you ever need to be able to repeat a run with the same seeds (sometimes helpful in debugging intermittent). And there may be other complications.

Comment: I want random seed for every instance, so if the seed is from 0 to 2^(8*4)-1 it's very probable that the seeds are different for every instances. I don't force the seeds to be different, even if maybe it would be better if they are. I think it's not a very big problem.

I don't need to repeeat run with the same seed.

Comment: Well, that's the easy case and you have good answers already. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from `/dev/random` is a good idea. Just convert the 4 byte string into an Integer:

```
f = open("/dev/random","rb")
rnd_str = f.read(4)
```

Either using struct:

```
import struct
rand_int = struct.unpack('I', rnd_string)[0]
```

**Update** Uppercase I is needed.

Or multiply and add:

```
rand_int = 0
for c in rnd_str:
    rand_int <<= 8
    rand_int += ord(c)
```

Comment: Note that if you go down that lane, remember to save your seeds to ensure that you can later reproduce the exact results.

Comment: I save the seed in the name of the output file

Comment: Thanks, but change 'i' to 'I' and rnd_string to rnd_str

Comment: Finally I change 'i' to 'I' because I got:
TypeError: void TRandom3::SetSeed(UInt_t seed = 0) =>
    could not convert argument 1 (can't convert negative value to unsigned long)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply copy over the four bytes into an integer, that should be the least of your worries.

But parallel pseudo-random number generation is a rather complex topic and very often not done well. Usually you generate seeds on one machine and distribute them to the others.

Take a look at [SPRNG](http://sprng.org/), which handles exactly your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Linux or a similar OS, you want `/dev/urandom` -- it always produces data immediately.

`/dev/random` may stall waiting for the system to gather randomness.  It does produce cryptographic-grade random numbers, but that is overkill for your problem.

Comment: I know, but I prefer random. I need only 4 bytes of random number, it's not too much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random number as the seed, which has the advantage of being operating-system agnostic (no /dev/random needed), with no conversion from string to int:

Why not simply use

```
random.randrange(-2**31, 2**31)
```

as the seed of each process?  Slightly different starting times give wildly different seeds, this way…

You could also alternatively use the `random.jumpahead` method, if you know roughly how many random numbers each process is going to use (the documentation of `random.WichmannHill.jumpahead` is useful).